Ubuntu 24.04 Remote Desktop with Dual Screens not working
I've got two Ubuntu 24.04 machines, both setups are the same (Shuttle DS77U + dual Dell 24" monitors at 1920x1080), I want to be able to remotely connect using the Remote Desktop RDP built into Ubuntu 24.04 and Remmina as the client and have dual screens.
Currently I've setup one machine with Remote Desktop switched on in the settings and I'm using the other machine to connect to that via Remmina.
The problem is that I only get the primary screen showing up on the client.
I've tried the following;

Remmina 1.4.35 (git 2a455ea) with settings 'Enable multi monitor' and 'Span screen over multiple monitors' turned on. I've also tried multiple combinations of that.

I swapped from Wayland on the server to X11 = one screen only

Tried connecting using xfreeRDP = one screen only
xfreerdp /multimon /u:username /v:server_address:server_port
xfreerdp /f /multimon /u:username /v:server_address:server_port
xfreerdp /multimon:force /monitors:0,1 /u:username /v:server_address:server_port /log-level:DEBUG


Ref debug output: https://pastebin.com/FYeNHfPk
UPDATE
I played around with the 'screen-share-mode' and got interesting results;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.rdp screen-share-mode mirror-primary

The default is mirror-primary which is what it's currently doing, I changed this to 'extend' but that now means I have the two monitors on the server and two on the client extends that to make it four monitors.
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.rdp screen-share-mode extend

It's still not what I want, but it does change the outcome. It would be nice if there was a 'mirror' screen share mode.
How do I get dual screens working remotely?
